# Why is my sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: always returning zero?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I'm trying to make a UITableViewCell that adjusts its height based on the length of a string it's displaying, but am getting hung up on this method.

Here's what I've got:

```
NSString *text = @"A really long string in here";
CGSize theSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(265.0f, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
NSString *stringHeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", theSize.height];
```

No matter what, `stringHeight` displays as `0`. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`CGFloat`s correspond to the C `float` data type; the proper format specifier for them is `%f`:

```
 NSString *text = @"A really long string in here"; 
 CGSize theSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(265.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
 NSString *stringHeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", theSize.height];
```

Also, you should use `CGFLOAT_MAX` instead of `MAXFLOAT`

Comment: Ahhh, switching to `%f` totally worked. I was under the impression that `%d` worked for `floats` too, but that clearly isn't the case. `MAXFLOAT` seems to work fine, though it would work just as well with a suitably large number. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Also, `%d` = signed int, not double (it's the same as `%i`). `%f` (or `%lf`) will work for both floats and doubles.

(Also, under 64-bit, CGFloat is a double, but that obviously doesn't apply here.)

Comment: The better constant here is probably CGFLOAT_MAX, but there's no danger of using MAXFLOAT. Either is clearer than picking a random large number, which might be interpreted by later readers as an intentional limit.

Comment: Thanks for the input; I've removed the erroneous information regarding doubles and switched to CGFLOAT_MAX

Answer (score 5):

You could also use

```
NSStringFromCGSize(theSize);
```