# How to set height dynamically of a uitextview

Tags: iphone, ios, height, uitextview

I want to set height dynamically on my UITextView, but it doesn't works. My code is :

```
 [super viewDidLoad];
 DTAttributedTextView *_textView;
contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.frame.size.height)];
_textView = [[DTAttributedTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 80.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.epnet.fr%@",[[[currentDicoNew valueForKey:@"image"] valueForKey:@"thumb_rect"] valueForKey:@"url"]]]]];
imageNew = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 178)];
imageNew.image = backgroundImage;
imageNew.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

CGSize maxImageSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 20.0, self.view.bounds.size.height);
NSString *html = [SundownWrapper convertMarkdownString:[currentDicoNew valueForKey:@"content"]];
NSData *HTMLData = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *options = @{ DTDefaultFontFamily : @"Helvetica",
                           DTDefaultFontSize : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:14.0],
                           DTDefaultLinkColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:174.0/255.0 blue:239.0/255.0 alpha:1],
                           DTMaxImageSize : [NSValue valueWithCGSize:maxImageSize],
                        };
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTMLData:HTMLData options:options documentAttributes:nil];

_textView.attributedString = attrString;
_textView.shouldDrawImages = YES;
_textView.shouldDrawLinks = YES;
_textView.textDelegate = self;
[_textView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 44, 0)];
_textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 54, 10);
[_textView.attributedTextContentView setNeedsDisplay];
[_textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
[contentView addSubview:_textView];

MDCParallaxView *parallaxView = [[MDCParallaxView alloc] initWithBackgroundView:imageNew
                                                                 foregroundView:contentView];
parallaxView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, self.view.frame.size.height);
parallaxView.backgroundHeight = 100;
parallaxView.scrollView.scrollsToTop = YES;
parallaxView.backgroundInteractionEnabled = YES;
parallaxView.scrollViewDelegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:parallaxView];
```

the height is equals to 420 (self.view.frame.size.height) but, I want to know how to retrieve the height of the dynamic content. Because, when I code this in the viewDidDisapear, it works but not in the ViewDidLoad:

```
CGRect frame1;
frame1 = _textView.frame;
frame1.size.height = [_textView contentSize].height;
_textView.frame = frame1;
NSLog(@"%f", frame1.size.height);
```

So, how I can set the height dynamically, please ? Many thanks

Comment: tried it already with `[_textView sizeToFit];` ?

Comment: yeah. Don't wanna work..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

```
-(CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size
```

This will return the size of the text that is to be fit inside the textview. You can set that size to the textview.

Comment: Ty. How can I use it? Knowing that it is not really a UITextView, but a DTAttributedTextView because text is parsed.

Comment: @Benjamin Why you can not use `attributeString` instead? You can use this method [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1352745/251513)

Comment: Hum, Because, there are images in the DTAttributedTextView... and this method supports string only... But why in the viewDidDisapear, this works correctly ? `CGRect frame1;
frame1 = _textView.frame;
frame1.size.height = [_textView contentSize].height;
_textView.frame = frame1;
NSLog(@"%f", frame1.size.height);`

Comment: I didn't use that class, but probably if it didn't work in the viewDidLoad it's beacuse your view is still loading, try to put your code in a method and call it with performSelector: after a little delay.

Comment: @Mat Yes, it runs but, the view is already loads with the self.view.frame.height .. Can I change it with the good height after 2 secs ?     _textView = [[DTAttributedTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 80.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one

```
  - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    CGSize size = [txtView.text sizeWithFont:txtView.font];
    CGRect f = txtView.frame;
    f.size.height = ceil(size.width/f.size.width)*size.height;
    txtView.frame = f;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't do this because, it's a DTAttributedTextView textView, because the text is parsed. And .text property is not allowed...

Comment: k...so don't implement it and i don't have any idea about DTAttributedTextView .